# Qt4 FSM: Is it possible to get transitions from QState?

Tags: qt4, fsm

I am missing a list of transitions in QState API. :-(

It is possible to get start-state and target-state from QAbstractTransition, I wonder, why is there no possibility for obtaining the list of transitions leading from one state to another - the state internally knows its transitions anyway.

Obtaining transition list from state would give a possibility for reverse engineering Qt4 FSMs e.g. using graphviz.

P.S.: Are transitions children of QState object? Could they be safely  obtained via children list?

Regards.

Comment: Meanwile I've found out, that transitions are the object-children of State. This works also: QList<MenuTransition*> transitions = curState->findChildren<MenuTransition*>(); Where MenuTransition is a subclass of QAbstractTransition. But the hint from Steffen is the right solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is possible for you, you could switch to Qt 4.7. They introduced a `QState::transitions()` method then, http://doc.troll.no/4.7/qstate.html#transitions